# How can I recycle controllers in UICollectionView's cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am displaying a number of cells, whose content is reasonably memory intensive. I have a custom controller that sets up a view to display the content, and updates the UI periodically. However, often `UICollectionView` asks for a particular cell several times. I want to know how to design (well) a system to re-use the controller + view if I have already created it for a given piece of data.  I thought about storing a controller reference in the data object, but don't know if storing UI elements in what is meant to be data is a good idea. Also, if I did this, I would need to monitor `retainCount` on cell unload, and when it gets to '1', remove it from the data object, which seems a bit hacky.  Similarly, a `NSDictionary` of data->controller pairs in the `UICollectionView` could also work, and would again require monitoring `retainCount`, or re-implementing a retain counting mechanism for my particular case.  It's doable, but seems clunky.

I'm very new to ios, so it may be I'm approaching this all wrong. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, think if displaying a controller view inside a cell is a good idea. I'm not sure, but since i'm not familiar with your project, it's something only you can tell.

Secondly, You can create your own pool of controllers. When you need a controller to put inside the cell (in cellforIndexPath method), take one from the pool. If the pool is empty, create a new one.  The cell shouldn't come with a controller of it's own, put it only in cellForItemMethod.